# Draw on margin of page with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, inline

Let me start by saying that I know my design is ridiculous. :) I have the following document.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{soul}

\newcommand{\customhl}[1]{\hl{#1}~\tikz[baseline=-2pt]{\draw[draw=none,fill=red] (-0.5,0.2) rectangle (0.5,-0.2);\node at(0,0) {cool!};}}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. \customhl{At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.} Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\subsection{Second}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \customhl{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.} Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

I have this label "cool!" next to each highlighted sentence but I would really like to put this label on the right margin of the page at the vertical level of the beginning of the highlighted text. Like so:

[image]

That is, I would need to teach tikz to draw on the margin. Any idea, how this can be achieved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is `\marginpar` which should also accept TikZ pictures.

Comment: why you not use `todo` package?

Comment: @TeXnician Can't believe I didn't find this...thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `tikz` and `tikzpagenodes` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\customhl}[2][cool!]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[fill=red,anchor=base west]
    at (0,0 -| current page marginpar area.north west)
    {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \hl{#2}
}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. \customhl{At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
  rebum.} Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\subsection{Second}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet. \customhl[hot!]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
  elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
  magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
  justo duo dolores et ea rebum.} Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I went for \marginpar but thank you for your working answer as well!